# Alpine linux: replace BusyBox tail to GNU tail

Tags: docker, tail, busybox, alpine-linux

I need to use the `tail ... --pid=PID` option in my docker container that is based on `Alpine` image in order to I can kill the running background tail process automatically.

Unfortunately the `BusyBox tail` that is available in the Alpine Docker image doesn't support this feature.

I am trying to find a material that describes the process how to replace it but no luck.

I don't want to use another base image because the image size is important.

Is it possible to switch to the GNU tail somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

```
apk add --no-cache bash coreutils
```

**Before:**

```
tail --version
tail: unrecognized option: version
BusyBox v1.35.0 (2022-11-19 10:13:10 UTC) multi-call binary.
```

**After:**

```
tail --version
tail (GNU coreutils) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```